# How to get numbers from the Paragraph tag?

Tags: jquery

I am having some values in my paragraph tag. I am trying to get the values from the paragraph tag. But I am unable to get the values. For example,

HTML Code:

```
<p id="value">1234567890</p>
```

I am trying to get this value. Is this possible of getting values from paragraph tag?

Comment: though this is possible (as described by @dystroy), you might want to consider adding an `data` attribute to your `<p>`.  Something like `<p id="value" data-myvalue="1234567890">1234567890</p>`. Then the value is accessible like this: `element.dataset.myvalue` and you don't need to worry about it getting contaminated with other text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a string :

```
 var str = $('#value').text()
```

As a number :

```
 var nb = parseInt($('#value').text().trim(), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to do

```
var value = $('#value').html();
```

That should give you the value you're looking for. The [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function returns all the html code within the selector. In your case it's just the text.

If you want that as a number instead of a string just wrap it in parseInt()

```
var integer_value = parseInt($('#value').html());
```